# Error when upgrading Android Studio to gradle version 5.6.4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':feature-ABC'.
> 'kotlin-android' expects one of the Android Gradle plugins to be applied to the project:
    * android
    * com.android.application
    * android-library
    * com.android.library
    * com.android.test
    * com.android.feature
    * com.android.dynamic-feature
    * com.android.instantapp
```

Gradle build is failing for an existing project after updating Android Studio gradle to 5.6.4. My plugin version is 3.6.1. It was previously working for Android Studio gradle 5.2.1 and plugin version 3.3.0.

I am relatively new to Android Studio so please ignore my ignorance about something basic that I might be missing. But this error really has me stumped.

EDIT: Posting build.gradle file

```
apply from: rootProject.file('jacoco-full-report.gradle')

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://microsoft-maps.bintray.com/Maven" }
    }

    dependencies {
        apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
        classpath pluginDep.androidGradle
        classpath pluginDep.jacoco
        classpath pluginDep.kotlin
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    jacoco {
        toolVersion = '0.8.2'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: When you are getting this error? Did you try Clear Cache and Restart?

Comment: Yep, I did. I'm not able to do Gradle build at all.

Comment: Post your build Gradle file.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun just did.

Comment: remove `~/.gradle` folder from system and `/build` from project

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how you're upgrading Android Studio to 5.6.4 when the latest version is 4.1 Canary 2.

Comment: @RyanMentley my bad, it's gradle version 5.6.4.

Comment: @silentsudo that does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I realise the source of the error now.

com.android.feature and various other plugins have been deprecated in the newer gradle version. So either I had to migrate to new plugins (instant apps) or revert to old gradle (which I am doing because this a collaborative project and I don't have the authority to make structural changes)